# How to get favicon url of current tab in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla, favicon

How to get favicon url of current tab in javascript or jquery without using ani 3rd party api or tool if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a minimal, working example of your attempt and clarify where you're stuck.

Comment: i havent tried anything i just saw some ways to do it but that included 3rd party apis. so im trying to know if there is a way of doing it using javascript or jquery.

Comment: In this case I recommend to go through "What topics can I ask about here?" [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ] and "How do I Ask a Good Question" [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ] and maybe edit your question accordingly.
The way it is currently phrased is unlikely to get you many answers, since it does not show more than minimal effort on your side trying to solve the problem on your own first - and the community usually is not too keen on oing other people's work for free.

Comment: with due respect im not asking someone to do my work here. only if someone is experienced with it so that i can get a direction to work on. but anyways the links u provided for asking a good question would really help me next time thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$($("link[rel=icon]")).attr("href");`

Comment: This is using jQuery, which is a 3rd party library.

Comment: It's not 3rd party to jQuery. "How to get favicon url of current tab in javascript or **jquery**", "How to get favicon url of current tab in javascript or **jquery** without using ani 3rd party api or tool if possible. Thanks in advance."

Comment: Fair, though I'm not quite getting why this question makes even sense, as jQUery already is a third party tool. +1 though anyway, as this solution should work.

Comment: It's definitely a weird question.

Comment: yes jquery is acceptable and thanks for the answer.